# Which text editor supports syntax highlighting for Wiki code?

Tags: ide, editor, wiki, syntax-highlighting, mediawiki

Does any text editor (such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/)) syntax highlight MediaWiki code? This might not be strictly programming related though the Wiki script is a language by itself.

Comment: Wikipedia has an extensive and updated list of the possible editor you can use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_editor_support

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want [Wikipedia:Text editor support - How to set up specific editors for Wikipedia editing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_editor_support#How_to_set_up_specific_editors_for_Wikipedia_editing).

At least 8 text editors support MediaWiki syntax highlighting:

- GNU Emacs
- Eclipse
- Vedit
- Vim
- jEdit
- Kate / KWrite
- NoteTab. (I assume that "Wikipedia" syntax just means MediaWiki syntax.)

Mac OSX

- SubEthaEdit
- TextMate

There is also a MediaWiki JavaScript add-on called [wikEd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/wikEd) that does syntax highlighting inside the MediaWiki edit box.

Comment: Best answer among the lot, gave me all the app choices instead of offering personal opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I hate to say it, being an avid Vim user, but **Emacs** supports wiki markup.

**Edit** Hold on a second, there is syntax highlighting for Vim too

http://fvue.nl/wiki/MediaWiki_syntax_highlighting_with_Vim

YAY!

Comment: +1 for placating the emacs and vim crowds. I'm in the latter :)

Comment: I had to Google "Vim+mediawiki+highlighting" to ensure I don't find a reason to switch to Emacs :P

Comment: Now now... lets be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Try out [e-text editor](https://github.com/etexteditor/e), which is Windows only.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look at this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Alex_Smotrov/ExtEdit

Alex also provides "userDefineLang.xml" -- a Notepad++ syntax highlight file.